# htacess mod_rewrite if file does not exist

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code in my .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?company_reference=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It checks to see if the file exists, and if not it will point it to a php get variable.

The only problem with this, is that when i go to "http://example.com" it gives a server misconfiguration message. If I go to "http://example.com/index.php" the website loads fine.

What do I need to do to make index.php load when I go to my domain without adding the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `DirectoryIndex`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?company_reference=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Perfect! That did it. Thank you for your help.